# Is their any alternative of HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE for large file offset?

Tags: winapi, iis, iis-7.5, iis-8, isapi

I have a problem with the HSE_TF_INFO Structure member Offset that is needed by HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE .

Let me explain my problem :

I have an ISAPI extension (32bits) that send back images to web client (JPEG less than 100 KBytes). As there is a large number of these images (more than 5 millions), I have created a file format that store (and indexe) all the images in a single file. Of course this file is larger than the 4GBytes limits of 32bits offsets.

So regarding the request, my ISAPI Extension seek at the good offset in the large file, read the small image and send it back to the client.
II try to improve response time of my ISAPI extension by sending this small images asynchronously as it seems to be more efficient.

So I try the HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE that is exactly what I need to send the small image wrapped in the large file with :

1. a file Handle (on the large file);
2. an Offset (of the small image);
3. and the size (of my small image).

But the HSE_TF_INFO::Offset is a DWORD, so limited to 4 Go !!!!!
So what is strange is that the ReadFile function (to read from a handle) as an OVERLAPED (structure that seems to be designed for async I/O) that as two Offset members (Offset and OffsetHigh) to emulate 64bits offsets and so support large file seeking.

Is there a kind of  HSE_TF_INFO_EX that can support large file offset ? or maybe is there a special way to use HSE_TF_INFO to seek in more than 4Gbytes files ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: [7 years ago](https://forums.iis.net/t/1181104.aspx)

Comment: yes and unfortunately in 7 years no answers on forums.iis.net :( maybe because you are not in this forum ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525867(v=vs.90).aspx) - this is more general than [`HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525816(v=vs.90).aspx). how you can view [`HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525867(v=vs.90).aspx) let send any numbers of [`HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525207(v=vs.90).aspx) structures. how we can view [`HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525207(v=vs.90).aspx) let send file or memory buffer. in case file - `cbOffset` (offset into the file) and `cbSize` ( number of bytes of file data from cbOffset) - both is `ULONGLONG` - so no restriction by size

demo (*purely for clarity*) how we can convert [`HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525867(v=vs.90).aspx) to more general [`HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525867(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
BOOL Repack(LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK lpECB, LPHSE_TF_INFO ti)
{
    // code have same effect as call 
    // lpECB->ServerSupportFunction(lpECB->ConnID, HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE, ti, 0, 0);

    if (lpECB->ServerSupportFunction(lpECB->ConnID, HSE_REQ_IO_COMPLETION, ti->pfnHseIO, 0, (DWORD*)ti->pContext))
    {
        HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT Element[3] = {
            { HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER, ti->pHead, 0, ti->HeadLength },
            { HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT_TYPE_FILE_HANDLE, ti->hFile, ti->Offset, ti->BytesToWrite },
            { HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER, ti->pTail, 0, ti->TailLength }
        };

        HSE_RESPONSE_VECTOR rv = {
            HSE_IO_ASYNC|HSE_IO_DISCONNECT_AFTER_SEND|HSE_IO_FINAL_SEND,
            0,
            0,
            RTL_NUMBER_OF(Element),
            Element
        };

        if (!Element[2].cbSize) rv.nElementCount--;

        if (!Element[0].cbSize) rv.lpElementArray++, rv.nElementCount--;

        if (lpECB->ServerSupportFunction(lpECB->ConnID, HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND, &rv, 0, 0))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

so you in general need next code if you need full 64bit size and offset:

```
struct TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT 
{
    ULONGLONG _BytesToWrite;
    ULONGLONG _cbOffset;
    HANDLE _hFile;
    char _szHeaders[];

    TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT(HANDLE hFile, ULONGLONG BytesToWrite, ULONGLONG _cbOffset);

    ~TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT();

    void* operator new(size_t cb, ULONG cbHeaders)
    {
        return ::operator new(cb + cbHeaders);
    }

    void operator delete(void* p)
    {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }

    static VOID WINAPI OnIoComplete (
        LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK lpECB,
        PVOID pContext,
        DWORD /*cbIO*/,
        DWORD dwError
        )
    {
        DbgPrint("OnIoComplete(%p, %u)\n", lpECB->ConnID, dwError);

        dwError = (dwError == NOERROR ? HSE_STATUS_SUCCESS : HSE_STATUS_ERROR);

        lpECB->ServerSupportFunction(lpECB->ConnID, HSE_REQ_DONE_WITH_SESSION, &dwError, 0, 0);

        delete reinterpret_cast<TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT*>(pContext);
    }

    DWORD Send(LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK lpECB)
    {
        if (lpECB->ServerSupportFunction(lpECB->ConnID, HSE_REQ_IO_COMPLETION, OnIoComplete, 0, (DWORD*)this))
        {
            HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT Element[2] = {
                { HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT_TYPE_MEMORY_BUFFER, _szHeaders, 0, strlen(_szHeaders) },
                { HSE_VECTOR_ELEMENT_TYPE_FILE_HANDLE, _hFile, _cbOffset, _BytesToWrite }
            };

            HSE_RESPONSE_VECTOR rv = {
                HSE_IO_ASYNC|HSE_IO_DISCONNECT_AFTER_SEND|HSE_IO_FINAL_SEND,
                0,
                0,
                RTL_NUMBER_OF(Element),
                Element
            };

            if (lpECB->ServerSupportFunction(lpECB->ConnID, HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND, &rv, 0, 0))
            {
                return HSE_STATUS_PENDING;
            }
        }

        delete this;

        return HSE_STATUS_ERROR;
    }
};

DWORD WINAPI HttpExtensionProc(LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK lpECB)
{
  //...
                if (TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT* p = new(cb + 1) TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT(*))
                {
                    //...

                    return p->Send(lpECB);
                }
    //...

    return HSE_STATUS_ERROR;
}
```

also note that both [`HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525867(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525816(v=vs.90).aspx) internal call [`HttpSendResponseEntityBody`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364500(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @RbMn i m happy that you are here, i didn't think about HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND. I let the question open few more day to let me the time to implement it and to validate it

Comment: @loki - the `HSE_REQ_TRANSMIT_FILE` is particular case of  `HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND`. i check yesterday this in self ISAPI Extension - perfect worked. first i think that this 2 requests mapped to `TransmitFile` and `TransmitPackets` but when debug code - view that on both `HSE_REQ_` really called the same `HttpSendResponseEntityBody`. in `HTTP_DATA_CHUNK` our data. for file chunk - in `HTTP_BYTE_RANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364515(v=vs.85).aspx) structure - where `StartingOffset` and `Length` both `ULARGE_INTEGER`

Comment: I believe that you're missing something important here - the cleanup of the hFile handle that was passed in. When you call vector send with HSE_IO_ASYNC specified in the flags, you essentially need to hand over ownership of the HANDLE to the TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT structure - making it responsible for closing the handle upon either OnIOComplete or the struct's destructor - otherwise you're going to leak file handles.

Comment: @CWoods - close file handle was in `~TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT();` - which called when operation finished. but code of destructor not shown in my code snippet

Comment: if `Send` fail ( say because `HSE_REQ_VECTOR_SEND` fail) - I just call `delete this` (so destructor called) and here file closed and other resource cleanup and return `HSE_STATUS_ERROR`. otherwise I return `HSE_STATUS_PENDING`. when `Send` finished - `OnIoComplete` called - here I complete initial operation `HSE_REQ_DONE_WITH_SESSION` and finally delete self - `delete reinterpret_cast<TRANSMIT_FILE_CONTEXT*>(pContext);` - so call destructor, where close file handle. so destructor called always and once - or just, if begin send fail, or when it finished